# Does the 'SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES *', work within java sql connector?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I am developing some code where I want all the max counts displayed to the user. Right now in the event of a tie the code will only display one as the max when there is ties. I am just curious how to do this as things I am trying just are not working.

```
  public static void m() throws SQLException {

       String max = "Select * from table1 order By H DESC";
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(max);

       if (rs.next()) {
           String an= rs.getString("an");          
           System.out.println("max: = " + an);

       }
  }
```

In the SELECT statement I tried to implement `SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES * FROM.....` and I get a `SQLException` error. Also I can get this to work but just enquiring for concise small code.

For example if animal 1's h is tied with animal 2 and 3's h, it should print all 3 names. But in this case I wrote above it just prints 1

Comment: What is your underlying SQL database (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: Please share the DDL of the underlying tables, sample data and expected output.

Comment: yes @a_horse_with_no_name , depending on the version which should be 12+

Comment: MySQL is the database I am using

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get count of all , you can use this

```
 "Select COUNT(*) from table1";
```

Comment: If I understand the OP's question I think they want the row(s) with the maximum value of something.

Comment: I want to return the row with the max h. I got it working for the 1 case, but if there is a tie (as everything is randomized through threads) it should print all of the max's and not just the first occurrence

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from table1 
where h = (select max(h) from table1)
```

Comment: this returns multiple max's? let me try

Comment: it only returned 1 of the max's in the output horse and deer had 3 each and it only returned deer

Comment: The inner query should return the maximum value of h, and the outer query should return all rows with this h value

Comment: String max = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE h= (Select max(h) from table1)";

Comment: Deer 2 2
Elephant 2 4
Giraffe 2 2
Horse 4 4
Zebra 0 0
Animal that was hungriest the most is: Name = Elephant

Comment: Elephant and Horse are both tied with 4 and it just prints Elephant

Comment: figured it out! just changed the if to a while statement